# Infinite statements from finite axioms

Tags: proof-explanation, first-order-logic, peano-axioms, incompleteness

I want to know if a given finite subset of axioms *of* PA1 ( 1st order peano arithmetic ) can prove infinite sentences in PA1 such that those proofs need no other axioms except those in the given finite set ? 
edit- from infinite sentences, i mean ' infinite number of sentences ' and not sentences of infinite length.

Since PA1 can prove the consistency of every given finite set of its axioms, so I think there should be only finite statements provable from a given finite set of axioms in PA1.

Also, for a given finite set of axioms of PA1, can PA1 itself prove that there are only finite number of statements provable from them ?

Comment: In a proof (well-ordered sequence of proof lines) of a statement of infinite length, there must be a first line of infinite length. This cannot be obtained from finitely many lines of finite length via any of the usual rules of inference, hence must be an axiom of infinite length

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen i think you misunderstood the question, i have edited the post now. From infinite sentences i mean infinite number of them, and  not infinite length of sentences

Comment: Sure. A tiny fragment of $\mathsf{PA}$, for example, is all that's needed to prove each of the following statements: "$2$ is prime," "$3$ is prime," "$5$ is prime," etc. Is this really what you're asking?

Comment: @NoahSchweber so we can actually prove infinite number of sentences from a finite subset of axioms of PA1, that sounds counter-intuitive to me for some reason, especially since i just found out PA1 proves every of finite subtheories of it are consistent ...  ....And what about the 2nd question , can it prove that   from a given finite subset of its axioms there are infinite number of sentences provable ?

Comment: @jason "can it prove that from a given finite subset of its axioms there are infinite number of sentences provable ?" Yes, quite easily. In fact, $PA$ proves that for each prime $p$, the theory $I\Sigma_1$ (a particular finite subtheory of $PA$) proves "$p$ is prime."

Comment: @NoahSchweber ah! yes.. offcourse...the example you gave was spot on... thanks

Comment: @NoahSchweber hey, if it isn't an inconvenience, can you write it as an answer, that both the questions asked above have positive answers, - from any given finite subset of axioms of PA1 we can prove infinite sentences, **and** PA1 itself proves this fact...   so that i could accept that as an answer, just for my assurance that i accepted the answer so the question is solved.....

Comment: @jason Sure, I've done so (and added a bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **yes**. Even ignoring silly examples like $$0=0, \quad 0=0\wedge 0=0,\quad (0=0\wedge 0=0)\wedge 0=0,\quad ...,$$ this can be done. A tiny fragment of $\mathsf{}$, for example, is all that's needed to prove each of the following statements: "2 is prime," "3 is prime," "5 is prime," etc. Moreover, $\mathsf{PA}$ proves that for each prime $p$, the theory $I\Sigma_1$ (a particular finite subtheory of $\mathsf{PA}$) proves "$p$ is prime."

In fact, $\mathsf{PA}$ proves that $I\Sigma_1$ is [$\Sigma_1$-complete](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258431/who-first-proved-that-we-can-prove-that-we-prove-things-we-prove), so that the $\Pi_1$-incompleteness established by Godel's incompleteness theorem is optimal in terms of complexity.

Comment: hey, i am sorry but i just need to clarify this one last thing - by *' any given finite subset of axioms of PA1 '* , i meant that there are no axiom schemas in that set, just plain 1st order closed sentences ( which are obviously finite in length ) , and only a finite number of such sentences. ' **Only finite number of  1st order closed sentences as axioms** ' is the phrase i am emphasizing here.  But that trivial *silly* example you gave looks like will need a axiom schema, and hence infinite number of axioms.... or not , i am a bit confused?

Comment: @jason Nope, it only needs finitely many axioms for the whole thing.

Comment: ohh... Okay then, well i mistakenly thought it needs an axiom schema for greater lengths.... my mistake, sorry.... and thanks! once again....

Comment: @jason Nope, it will just need longer and longer *proofs*. Think about how we only need finitely many axioms (distributivity, commutativity, associativity) to simplify any expression built out of $1$,$+$, and $\times$, but for really long expressions the corresponding proofs will be really long as well. Crucially, *we can re-use axioms* (and most of our axioms have the form "$\forall x[\mathit{stuff}]$" so they have infinitely many *instances*).

Comment: ' we can re-use axioms ', yes i  figured we would need to do that...